# Misuse of subject pronouns where there are two or more objects

Tags: word-usage

I've noticed that in cases where there are multiple (direct, indirect or prepositional) objects in a sentence, there is a tendency for individuals to use subject pronouns because it "sounds better" or "more refined." E.g., "The celebration was held in honor of both John and I."  "The new rule only applied to Alex and she."  Am I being overaly pedantic to even care about such trivialities, or do such basic points of grammar even matter anymore in modern English?

Comment: It's all about the function of the coordination. The rule is that where it is object of a prep, an accusative pronoun is correct ("This is for John and me"), but where it is subject, a nominative  pronoun is correct ("John and I played football").

Answer (score 2):

You are describing a linguistic phenomenon called **hypercorrection**. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection#Personal_pronouns) has a useful article about it and links to some sources.

This particular hypercorrection seems to have evolved like this:

1. Young people say things like "Me and John went to the store."
2. A parent or teacher says, "You mean 'John and I.'"
3. The young person now believes that "John and I" is correct whenever it is coordinated with a noun phrase.
4. Speakers at large get so accustomed to hearing "John and I" as an object that they adopt it as well, even if they have not personally been corrected.

We might be seeing the emergence of a new rule, at least in spoken English: Where a pronoun is coordinated with another noun phrase, the pronoun must be in the subjective/nominative case — or something like that.

That being said, no one has ever challenged me when I have used the traditional rule, and I advise you to use it as well.

Comment: Thanks, Mr. Carney, for your response.  I did read the section in Wikipedia that you linked and found the explanation of "over correction" exactly what I assumed, a form of false generalization.   However, the opinion by Huddleston and Pullum is unpersuasive.  The fact that "standard English speakers say it all the time" seems a weak excuse for what boils down to bad grammar.